# comment_author also returns the ip

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin, that gets the comment authors name by "$comment->comment_author", but apparently this also gives you the authors ip and gateway, etc.

Is this normal behaviour or is there a way to stop this?

this is how the email looks:

```
Autor: Carlotta (IP: xxx.xxx.xxx , xxxx.adsl.highway.telekom.at)
E-Mail : xxx@student.tugraz.at
URL: 
Whois: http://whois.arin.net/rest/ip/xx.114.244.129
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You'll either need to show some code, or contact the author, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thats the file in question: https://github.com/stcr/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/blob/master/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded/subscribe-to-comments-reloaded.php but it seems that this is coming directly from wordpress

Comment: sry, the problem is resolved! The Email to the users looks fine, but its the email to the site admin, that looks like this, which isn´t a problem! Thanks anyways :)

Comment: I was halfway through writing an answer saying just that - I'll carry on in case someone finds this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are the site administrator then WordPress will send you this information by default, however it is only the site admin who sees it, and not your average user.

Answer (score 0):

sry, the problem is resolved! The Email to the users looks fine, but its the email to the site admin, that looks like this, which isn´t a problem! Thanks anyways :)